# Jboss server startup time depends on number of war files

Tags: jboss, liferay, war, portal, app-startup

Does Java EE server startup time depends on the number of WAR files?

I am working on a portal server which is deployed with 20 different Portlets (20 WAR files). The portal and Portlets are deployed in a JBoss 5 server. Right now, the server itself takes anywhere between 15 - 20 mins to start.

I am trying to see if I can tweak the JBoss configuration to deploy multiple WAR files at the same time. Is that a good option? Are there any other ways to improve the startup time?

Answer (score 0):

Of course that the portal startup time depends the number of deployed portlets, even though 15 minutes to deploy 20 portlets I think it is excessive.

I've never used JBoss as application server, but with Tomcat the startup speed depends basically of two things:

- The number of deployed portlets: The more portlets deployed, more
  time gets the portal to be started.
- The memory allocated: The more memory allocated to the application
  server, less time to start the portal.

There can be something more to check, but (at least for me) these are the most important causes.

As you probably can not reduce the number of portlets, you'll have to try to increase the memory allocated to JBoss.